# Both my apple trees have white powder on this particular branch in this particular spot. What should I do?

Tags: apples

I have two young apple trees that are roughly a year appart (that I grew from seeds without grafting).

Both of them have one particular new branch where all the leaves and the sprout have this white powdery aspect to them. The rest of the trees seem to be mostly fine.

**What is this and what should I do about it?**

### Tree 1:

[image][image]

### Tree 2:

[image: Closeup tree 1][image]

The trees are positioned next to each other and the affected branch faces the same general direction for both, and is roughly at the same height.